# Direct2D in desktop application and IE plugins

Tags: visual-c++, internet-explorer-11, directx-11

I observe strange behavior of the same code used in desktop application and IE11 plugin.
I'm adding OSD and some geometry to video frame using DirectDraw and Direct2D which works fine in desktop application. The same code is used in IE11 plugin but none of above appear on the video. In both cases I recalculate positions to match the current frame size and it works flawlessly in desktop. Once I switch to IE, everything is drawn off-screen. Once I stop recalculating positions it starts to appear in IE plugin (not exactly where it should be) but in desktop it looks definitely wrong. Frame sizes and coordinates (recalculated) are the same for both cases (added printouts to validate it).
 What is the problem could be and why it behaves differently between desktop and IE plugin?
Running on Win10 x64, IE11, DirectX11
Sorry, providing minimal reproducible example is quite problematic in this case, but I can try and show the code (quite a big chunk) if someone interested.

EDIT001: Oddly it works on another Win10 machine as expected. Have to be something with my local machine, the question is what is it.

Comment: Have you verified that IE11 is not configured to use software rendering (Internet Options | Advanced)?  Also, have you enabled the `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING` [feature control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#gpu_rendering) for your app?

Comment: Was not aware of this setting, but the "Use software rendering" is unchecked. As of `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING`, I dont have this entry in the registry, should I add it? On the other hand, how it could affect the positioning? If the  rendering was not working altogether I would believe it is enable/disable stuff in the machine settings, but it works, just not as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm not an expert in DX programming.  If the drawing is similar but the coordinates are off, that may reflect a difference between containers, parent handles, and/or offsets.  Perhaps you can detect the situation and scale accordingly?  As far as the setting goes, your app will not take advantage of any hardware acceleration built into the WebBrowser control unless the feature is enabled via the Registry.  I don't have visibility into what that might be, but you could enable the feature control as a test and see if there's any improvement over not enabling the feature.

Comment: Will try to add it to the registry. See question update, I dont believe the code should be changed since it works on another machine as expected.

Comment: Try comparing `dxdiag /t` reports for each machine.  I suspect you'll find there are driver or other version differences.

Comment: good idea! Thanks! But I know drivers are different, but the latest for the hardware